# Show Markers on google map by using data from mysql in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I attached image here for an example.[image: I want that the location with marker and it's description will show something like this in map but from MySQL database with php. so, if some new stores is added then i quickly update it from DB.]

Currently I show locations on map in a HTML page with static code like,

Java scripts to load map on page :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"> </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   var map;
   var centerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(37.0902,95.7129);
   var zoomLevel = 4;
   function initialize() 
    {
      var mapOptions = 
      {
       center: centerPos,
       zoom: zoomLevel
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions );
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
```

Google map Div :

```
    <div id="Community-Google-Map-Div">
          <div class="wrap">
            <div id="map-canvas">
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Java scripts to load Different locations :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function LocateSales() 
    {
      var map;
      var centerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(22.4700,77.5667);
      var zoomLevel = 4;

      var mapOptions = 
      {
        center: centerPos,
        zoom: zoomLevel
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions );

      var locations = [ ['USA', 50.0000, 79.7800],
                        ['Second', 82.9667, 77.5667],
                        ['Third', 78.4700, 77.0300]
                      ];

          for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      title: locations[i][0],map: map });
       }
  }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
```

So, Please tell me how to solved this !

Comment: So, please tell us what's wrong?

Comment: any error in code?

Comment: the contents i retrieve is from array "var locations =" that is fix if i want to add new location then i edit my javascript code every time so, i want to retrieve it from database. but, don't know how to done this with php and mysql ?

Comment: no no error in the code its working fine.

Comment: try to add code manually in var locations = [ ['<?php echo $data; ?>'....

Comment: But, how any idea ?

Comment: do an ajax request, get the stuff from db, echo as json. retrieve data back from front end. use jquery to append them to the array and redraw the map pins. easy stuff.

Comment: Create a json array and store in a js variable just before calling map js and pass it to the locations.

Comment: I don't understand how to solve this problem. I don't know php very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your response but I got answer. I post it here,

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("slcommunitydb") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps</title>

<!-------- Customizable Css for Map  ----------------------------->
    <style type="text/css">
        body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
        #map { width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    </style>

    <!---------------- Java Scripts for Map  ----------------->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sensor=false" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!------------- Java Scripts for Map  ------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //--------------------- Sample code written by vIr ------------
    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
               new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
               new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
                    var center = null;
                    var map = null;
                    var currentPopup;
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                        bounds.extend(pt);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: pt,
                            icon: icon,
                            map: map
                        });
                        var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: info,
                            maxWidth: 300
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                            if (currentPopup != null) {
                                currentPopup.close();
                                currentPopup = null;
                            }
                            popup.open(map, marker);
                            currentPopup = popup;
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                            map.panTo(center);
                            currentPopup = null;
                        });
                    }           
                    function initMap() {
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {

                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                            zoom: 14,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                            mapTypeControl: true,
                            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                            },
                            navigationControl: true,
                            navigationControlOptions: {
                                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                            }
                        });
     <?php

     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM salesmapmarkers")or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
      $name = $row['name'];
      $lat = $row['lat'];
      $lon = $row['lon'];
      $desc = $row['desc'];

   echo("addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>$name</b><br />$desc');\n");
   }
  ?>
   center = bounds.getCenter();
   map.fitBounds(bounds);

   }
   </script>

  </head>
    <body onLoad="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
       <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ajax with php file like this :

jQuery:

```
function getLocations()
{
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json",
        url: "yourPhpFile.php",
        success: function(locations)
        {
            //place markers
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("error");
        }
    });


}
```

In your PHP file, you should connect to your DB -> execute a query on your table (name, long, lat). End with `echo json_encode($yourarray);`

"$yourarray" will become "location" in ajax (JSON object).

note : I advise you PDO to connect on your DB (http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php)